# Fiat-Shamir with interactions

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, random-oracle-model, fiat-shamir, sigma-protocol

Suppose we have a standard $\Sigma$-protocol for proving the knowledge of a witness $x$ for the statement $y$. It has an honest-verifier ZK and special soundness. Now we do an unusual modification to get an interactive $\Sigma'$-protocol in ROM:

1. The prover $\mathcal{P}$ compute $a$ exactly like in $\Sigma$-protocol and sends it to the verifier $\mathcal{V}$.
2. The verifier $\mathcal{V}$ replies with a challenge $e$. So far, everything is like in $\Sigma$-protocol.
3. **Modification:** The prover $\mathcal{P}$ computes $e' = \textsf{Hash}(e)$ and uses $e'$ as the challenge to compute the answer $z$.

Has anyone seen this construction mentioned anywhere? I think it should have full ZK in ROM, but I never saw anything similar. Is it because $\Sigma'$ is folklore/not very useful, or am I wrong about the full ZK?

Comment: So your goal is taking a $\Sigma$-protocol that is only known to be HVZK and making it ZK?

Comment: Yes, interactive protocol with ZK in ROM by just hashing the challenge before applying it. I just wonder if anyone was looking into something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Fiat-Shamir transform, HVZK becomes ZK because the verifier sends nothing to the prover. The ZK simulator generates $(a,e,z)$ from the HVZK simulator and reprograms the oracle so that $H(a)=e$. This works because $c$ is uniformly random and the verifier cannot have known the value of $H(a)$ before the reprogramming (except with negligible probability).

A similar trick doesn't work with the scheme you propose since the verifier can query $H(e)$ before step 2, making reprogramming harder. The verifier can also influence the distribution of $e'$, for example by querying the oracle on many points and rejection sampling. If the simulator could somehow guess the challenge $e$, it could generate a transcript for a uniformly random challenge $e'$ and reprogram the oracle as $H(e)=e'$. But the probability of making the right guess is exponential in the size of $e$ and even if we were to make this size logarithmic and use rewinding, we run into issues. The verifier could compute the full table for $H(e')$ since there are only polynomially many possible values, making reprogramming impossible.

But as you hinted in your question, this scheme does not seem all that useful, especially in a model (the ROM) where you can make the whole thing non-interactive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question, if the whole issue is that the verifier can query Hash(e) multiple times and affect the distribution, does it mean that setting $e'= Hash(e, a, y)$ would fix it?

Comment: At first glance, providing additional inputs to $H$ seems to prevent the problems I've outlined.